KeyError indexing - when doing MCAR test
Trying to run MCARTest but getting error:
KeyError: "['acer_37_acertot', 'acer_38_atttot', 'acer_39_memtot'] not in index"
data_mcar = X
mt = MCARTest(method="little")
print(mt.little_mcar_test(data_mcar))

print(X.columns)


Index(['acer_37_acertot', 'acer_38_atttot', 'acer_39_memtot'])
X is a dataframe with Nan values and columns are of type object.
Any idea how to solve this problem? (for https://rianneschouten.github.io/pyampute/build/html/pyampute.exploration.html#pyampute.exploration.mcar_statistical_tests.MCARTest).
